# Resource not loaded with PrismApplication (Prism v7 - 7.0.0.329-ci)

Tags: wpf, prism

Using the new Prism v7 library, the `Bootstrapper` class is obsolete and must be replaced by the `PrismApplication` class.

I configured the new `PrismApplication` for my app but the app failed to load the XAML resources at the right time.

I declare a few resources in the `App.xaml` file:

```
<local:MyPrismApplication x:Class="Xxx.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xxx">
    <local:MyPrismApplication.Resources>
...
    </local:MyPrismApplication.Resources>
</local:MyPrismApplication>
```

The new `PrismApplication` creates the `Shell`. The `Shell` need resources that aren't yet loaded.

Using the 'old' bootstrapper class, the problem doesn't exist.

What is recommended with the new `PrismApplication` class? Can we not set up anymore the resources in the `App.xaml` ?

Comment: What is MyPrismApplication? Are you calling InitializeComponent() somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may have found a bug. I changed the startup process to start in the Ctor, not in the OnStartup override. I should probably change it back to do everything in OnStartup instead, similar to the bootstrapper. This will ensure all resources are available. Can you submit a bug on the GitHub site?

https://github.com/prismlibrary/prism/issues

EDIT: Just updated the PrismApplication class. Try the latest CI build and see if it works.

Comment: I will test the new release first thing tomorrow (Brussels time). Do you still need the bug to be filled on GitHub?

Comment: No need to submit this bug, but be sure to submit anything else you find with this new PrismApplicaton class.